# Why did I get Wrong Answer on this problem(Uva OJ 455)

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm crazy about [this problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=396) (Uva 455):

> A character string is said to have period *k* if it can be formed by
>   concatenating one or more repetitions of another string of length *k*.
>   For example, the string ”`abcabcabcabc`” has period 3, since it is
>   formed by 4 repetitions of the string ”`abc`”. It also has periods 6
>   (two repetitions of ”`abcabc`”) and 12 (one repetition of
>   ”`abcabcabcabc`”).
>
> Write a program to read a character string and
>   determine its smallest period.
>
> ## Input
>
> The first line oif the input file
>   will contain a single integer *N* indicating how many test case that
>   your program will test followed by a blank line. Each test case will
>   contain a single character string of up to 80 non-blank characters.
>   Two consecutive input will separated by a blank line.
>
> ## Output
>
> An
>   integer denoting the smallest period of the input string for each
>   input. Two consecutive output are separated by a blank line.
>
> ## Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1
>
> HoHoHo
> ```
>
> ## Sample Output
>
> ```
> 2
> ```

I've checked all test cases I could imagine and all of them returned correct result, but I still get Wrong Answer on the online judge. Where did I go wrong?
(English is not my native language; please excuse typing or syntax errors.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define maxn 85

int check(char* s, int per){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s) - per; i++){
        if(s[i + per] != s[i])  return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    char s[maxn];
    while(T--){
        scanf("%s", s);
        int len = strlen(s);
        bool OK = false;
    for(int i = 1; i <= len/2 && (len % i == 0); i++){//That's wrong.
        if(check(s, i)){
            printf("%d\n", i);
        OK = true;
        break;
        }
    }
        if(!OK) printf("%d\n", len);
        if(T)   printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't even compile, because you left out your #include's. 2. Even when I add them, it gives the wrong answer on every nontrivial test case (i.e. any case where the period is less than the length of the line). What did you even test this on?

Comment: I'd expect to see modulo (`%`) used in solving this problem, but I don't see it.

Comment: 1.Sorry about that I thought it could be easier to read. 2.Could you tell me which test case you used? Thank you!

Comment: @Leon.L 1. Please edit your question and add them. 2. "abcabcabcabc" should be 3, but your program says it's 12.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Hmm, I must have messed something up somewhere. Okay, here's one that really fails: "abcdabcd" should be 4, but it's 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `for(int i = 1; i <= len/2 && (len % i == 0); i++)`. You are stopping as soon as you encounter an `i` that doesn't divide `len`, instead of skipping it.

Write the loop as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= len/2; i++) {
    if (len % i != 0) continue;

    ...
}
```